# How to suppress warnings when building an ASP.NET 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-core

The ASP.NET 5 project has no "Suppress Warnings" option in its project property sheet.

Recently I encountered a warning MSB3274 ( [dnx451 actually means .net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634186/dnx451-actually-means-net-4-5) ) and I tried to find a way to suppress this warning.

I looked https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file but found nothing related to suppress warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet supported, the DNX team will try to add it in beta 6: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2042.