# How should I design my visual studio solutions with the new class library nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget-package, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 folders:

```
My-WebApplication
My-WebService
```

Both are 2 asp.net **mvc 6.0** project in an extra visual studio solution.

Both need to share a custom `DbContext` class using **Entity Framework 7**.

I use **Visual Studio 2015** and develop against

```
"frameworks" : { "net451" }
```

Where would you create the custom `DbContext` class and how would you share it among both VS solutions using the latest features of Visual Studio 2015 concerning **class libraries as nuget packages** - if that helps -

**OR**

should I just create a class library and put that in a 3rd share.sln file in a 3rd folder on the same level as the others? and both solutions reference then this class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common DbContext in a separate assembly (package class library) . DbContext is initiated separately for each project in *ConfigureServices* of *Startup.cs*

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]));
```

It is necessary to specify dependencies for each project in *project.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "YourProject.Data": "1.0.0.0",
    ...
}
```

where *YouProject.Data* is an assembly with *YourDbContext*.

Also you need to add dependencies and the command in *YouProject.Data project.json* for a configuration of migrations for your context:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7"
}
"commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
```

You can use the next command for a creation of new migration (for MVC6 beta-7)

> dnx ef migrations add NameOfMigraion -c YourDbContext -s YouApplicationProjectName

where *YouApplicationProjectName* is a name of your asp.net mvc6 project name, for example *My-WebApplication* or *My-WebService*

I hope this will help you.

Comment: When each project`s project.json references the "YourProject.Data".assembly, where is this assembly put? In which file location? folder 1 or folder 2 and why you decide for that?

Comment: If you have a separate solutions, you can put the assembly anywhere but you must add it in both solutions to keep references.

Comment: ok I build those assembly to share in a CommonShare folder on the same directory level as both solutions. That way each solution can reference the assembly. Is there an advantage in using a class library as nuget package here? Else I use a common class library.

Comment: There are a  [number of benefits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034174/why-create-an-asp-net-5-class-library-project) of _Class Library (Package)_ over _Class Library (.csproj)_ projects: